# Changing Scale of Sprite with SKAction.scale

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode8

Trying to have the scale of the sprite 'PlayButton' continue to scale up and down to hint to the user to touch it. Can't seem to get it working.

This is the Menu Class:

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {

let ScalePBup = SKAction.scaleX(to: 300, y: 300, duration: 10)
let ScalePBdown = SKAction.scaleX(to: -300, y: -300, duration: 10)

//MARK: - Private Instance Variables
private let logo = GameLogo()
private let title = GameTitle()
private let playButton = PlayButton()
private let background = Background()
private let foreground = Foreground()
private let background2 = Background2()

//MARK: - Init
required init ?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
}
override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)
}
override func didMove(to view: SKView){
    self.setup()
}
//MARK: - Setup
private func setup() {

    self.backgroundColor = Colors.colorFromRGB(rgbvalue: Colors.background)
    self.addChild(logo)
    self.addChild(title)
    self.addChild(playButton)
    self.addChild(background)
    self.addChild(foreground)
    self.addChild(background2)        
}

// MARK: - Update
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {}
// MARK: - Touch Handling
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    if playButton.contains(touchLocation){
        loadScene()
    }
}

// MARK: - Load Scene
private func loadScene() {
    let scene = GameScene(size: kViewSize)
    let transition = SKTransition.fade(with: SKColor.black, duration: 0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run(ScalePBup, onChildWithName: "playButton"),
        SKAction.run(ScalePBdown, onChildWithName: "playButton")
        ])
    ))
}
}
```

Here is the sprite

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayButton: SKSpriteNode {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
}

convenience init() {
    let texture = GameTextures.sharedInstance.texture(name: SpriteName.playButton)
    self.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.white, size: texture.size())

    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    self.position = CGPoint(x: kViewSize.width / 2, y: kViewSize.height * 0.2)
}

}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **MenuScene** remove the code:

```
run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run(ScalePBup, onChildWithName: "playButton"),
        SKAction.run(ScalePBdown, onChildWithName: "playButton")
        ])
    ))
```

in **class PlayButton** add:

```
let ScalePBup = SKAction.scaleX(to: 300, y: 300, duration: 10)
let ScalePBdown = SKAction.scaleX(to: -300, y: -300, duration: 10)

func startPulse() {
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([ScalePBup,ScalePBdown])))
}

func removePulse () {
    removeAllAction()
}
```

in **MenuScene**

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView){
    self.setup()
    playButton.startPulse()
}
```